# “An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll”

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb, oledbconnection

I use microsoft access 2013  (database name:kyt, table name:vg_info_table). When I run this code it works, but when I choose the selected value from the combobox and click the send button (a value should be recorded to my database; vg_1 field) I get an error(`komut.ExecuteNonQuery();`):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in
>
> System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not
>   been initialized.

my whole code is here;

```
namespace afeusdotnet
{

    public partial class verigirisekranisorular1 : UserControl {

    OleDbConnection bag = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=kyt.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"); 

    DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adptr = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand();
    DataSet dset = new DataSet();
    verigirisekranisorular2 soru2 = new verigirisekranisorular2();

    public verigirisekranisorular1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void Listele(){  
        bag.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adptr = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From vg_info_table", bag);   
        adptr.Fill(tablo); 
        adptr.Dispose();
        bag.Close();
    }    

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (comboBox1.Text.ToString() == "")
            MessageBox.Show("ilgili alanları doldurunuz");
        else {

               bag.Open();

               komut.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vg_info_table(vg_1) VALUES ('" + comboBox1.Text.ToString() + "')";
               komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

               bag.Close();    
               Listele();
               MessageBox.Show("kaydınız tamamlandı diğer sayfaya geçiniz");
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: You need to pass the connection to the oledbcommand inside the constructor.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the connection to the `OleDbCommand`.

```
komut.Connection = bag;
komut.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vg_info_table(vg_1) VALUES ('" + comboBox1.Text.ToString() +"')";
bag.Open();
komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Apart from that you should use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent sql-injection (among other things).

Comment: **warning** this code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Tim, I love you man, I've read about 100 pages on how to get my localdb connection to work, not once did anyone say just pass the SqlConnection to the SqlCommand. Although it seems obvious once you know.

Comment: @Scriven: that's why i prefer the constructor of `SqlCommand` that takes the `Connection` and the query. So i cannot forget to assign it ;)